# Are the Gateway IP and DNS IP of a Kubernetes cluster same as the Gateway IP and DNS IP of the host machine?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dns

Is DNS IP or Gateway IP of the Kubernetes cluster same as host machine?

I was doing some learning and deployed a web service in a POD. This service is exposing an endpoint  http://localhost:8080/health. This API internally calls an endpoint https://www.google.com and it is working fine.

How does Kubernetes resolve domain name and call the external endpoint https://www.google.com?

This is my understanding, correct me if I am wrong:

- DNS IP address of POD network calls to the kube-DNS server of Kubernetes.
- kube-DNS server has the DNS IP address similar to host machine which would be of Internet
  provider. So, kube-DNS server call to that DNS IP address to resolve the domain name.
- Once domain name is resolved, kube-DNS send resolved IP address to the POD and then POD invoked
  to resolved IP address.
- Again, This resolved IP doesn't belong to the same network of POD. So, This will be routed to
  the Gateway IP of cluster. And this Gateway IP of cluster should be similar to the host
  machine. As host machine gateway IP is of Internet provider, Cluster gateway IP will also point
  to internet provider.
- Internet provider calls to actual endpoint and response send back to the cluster gateway IP and
  from there, POD get the response.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but networking and DNS, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Stackexchange is not providing tag for kubernetes or docker. Just for you information, Kubernetes and docker is tool which is widely used by developers. So, I request you to reopen this question.

Comment: Have you checked my below comment

Answer (score 0):

From the data provided by you it can be considered you are asking about a Data center environment/server based deployment and it’s a single node based deployment.

There is a server and on that server you have installed your kubernetes cluster, after creating a single node cluster you have deployed your application on this kubernetes cluster.

So, to clarify your queries the first thing you need to check is the network CIDR for your kubernetes cluster and your host(Node: In kubernetes the term used for base machines is node) will be different and if you don’t expose the ports on which your application is running you can’t access the application even from a different POD.

For making your application reachable outside you need to use following kubernetes services:

> **ClusterIP** (default) - Exposes the Service on an internal IP in the cluster. This type makes the Service only reachable from within the
> cluster.
>
> **NodePort** - Exposes the Service on the same port of each selected Node in the cluster using NAT. Makes a Service accessible from outside
> the cluster using :. Superset of ClusterIP.
>
> **LoadBalancer** - Creates an external load balancer in the current cloud (if supported) and assigns a fixed, external IP to the Service.
> Superset of NodePort.
>
> **ExternalName** - Maps the Service to the contents of the externalName field (e.g. foo.bar.example.com), by returning a CNAME
> record with its value. No proxying of any kind is set up. This type
> requires v1.7 or higher of kube-dns, or CoreDNS version 0.0.8 or
> higher.

Go through the “Using a Service to Expose Your App” [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/) on kubernetes official forum for more information.

Once you have exposed your application from your kubernetes network to the private network(host network), you can use the firewall or dns server for redirection.

So the flow looks like this

```
Users → Internet → firewall/gateway of DC/local network → host machine(In case of single node)


host machine → kubernetes service → kubernetes pod
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sai. But It didn't answer my questions. How domain name resolution takes place in Kubernetes environment for google.com and how exactly IP(corresponding to google.com) request reach to google server from Kubernetes cluster's Pod.

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview) more information about how exactly IP(corresponding to google.com) request reach to google server from Kubernetes cluster's Pod